# How do I use my personal computer to receive callbacks from a REST API?

Tags: javascript, callback, uri

I am currently working with the ETSI MEC Sandbox (more info at https://try-mec.etsi.org/).
I am trying to set up subscriptions, whereby changes detected in the Sandbox prompt the server to send a notification describing the change to my computer (or wherever I specify).

I am using a python script to interact with the Sandbox through the API provided. However, while making these subscription requests, a parameter I have to pass is the 'callback_reference'. The ETSI document over at the [forge](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/MEC/001_099/012/02.01.01_60/gs_mec012v020101p.pdf) describes this as: "URI selected by the service consumer to receive notifications on the subscribed RNIS information. This shall be included both in the request and in response."

I understand that a domain can be connected to this to receive requests. However, I do not own any domains, and wanted to instead provide an address to my computer and simply receive the responses by listening over a port. Providing just my public IP as the callback reference isn't enough because there's multiple devices on my network. How do I specify exactly which device and port I need the callback sent to?

Comment: if your LAN is behind a NAT router, which is most likely the case based on your last statement, then you'll need to set up port forwarding on your network router to forward the port used for the callback URI to the computer running the network server software that you'll write that will handle the notification from ETSI - none of this has to do with javascript, and most of it has nothing to do with coding at all

Comment: Oh, thank you! I'll try to set up port forwarding in this case and see whether this works. The API treated the callback reference as a javascript object so I thought there might be something funky that could be done. Apologies for the misleading tag!